# How can I queue data range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data ranges that start at the same time.
How can I queue them in SQL Server?

For example, this datasets:

```
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| OrderId |          StartTime          |         FinishTime          |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|      16 | 2017-09-11 11:00:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 11:02:30.0000000 |
|      17 | 2017-09-11 18:40:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:42:10.0000000 |
|      18 | 2017-09-11 18:40:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:41:00.0000000 |
|      19 | 2017-09-11 18:43:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:43:05.0000000 |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Should became:

```
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| OrderId |          StartTime          |         FinishTime          |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|      16 | 2017-09-11 11:00:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 11:02:30.0000000 |
|      17 | 2017-09-11 18:40:00.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:42:10.0000000 |
|      18 | 2017-09-11 18:42:10.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:43:10.0000000 |
|      19 | 2017-09-11 18:43:10.0000000 | 2017-09-11 18:43:15.0000000 |
+---------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

You can notice that orders 17, 18, 19 shifted.

You can use this command:

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE
(OrderId int, StartTime datetime2, FinishTime datetime2)

INSERT INTO @Orders (OrderId, StartTime, FinishTime)
VALUES (15, '2017-09-11 11:00:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 11:02:00.0000000')
, (16, '2017-09-11 11:00:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 11:02:30.0000000')
, (17, '2017-09-11 18:40:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 18:42:10.0000000')
, (18, '2017-09-11 18:40:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 18:41:00.0000000')
, (19, '2017-09-11 18:43:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 18:43:05.0000000')
, (21, '2017-09-11 19:30:00.0000000', '2017-09-11 19:30:40.0000000')
```

Many thanks

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is, frustratingly, recursively; as any "spill over" could affect a row that previously didn't appear to be. It would seem ideal that you also don't allow such data to be inserted. Have you considered adding that kind of validation?

Comment: How do You decide that startTime at orderID 17 must be 18:40 not 11:02 ? I think You should implement all needed logic when You insert data to table, that would be easier

Comment: @Larnu. Unfortunately I can't manage CRUD operations on orders, I receive them from different sources and I "only" have to schedule them.

Comment: @KubaDo. I don't decide start time, I receive it.

Comment: @fbognini within Your expected output, startTime = FinishTime from previous record.
By hand You have changed few values. What is the logic of that output ?

Comment: @KubaDo. When StartTime < FinishTime from previous record: StartTime = FinishTime from previous record AND FinishTime = FinishTime + execution time of previous record (difference between start and finish)

Comment: There may be a non-recursive solution through sufficiently clever use of windowed aggregates, but that's only an inkling I have and not something I can directly translate to a query.

Comment: The DDL of your table, and the values you insert don't make sense. For the first row, you insert **4** columns, but for all the other 3. Also, the column `Seconds` is defined as an `int`, however, the data you `INSERT` is a date and time.

Comment: @Larnu. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of operation requires a recursive CTE, because you do not know when the existing start time is good enough.

The code looks like:

```
with o as (
      select o.*
      from (select o.*, row_number() over (order by starttime) as seqnum
            from orders o
           ) o
     ),
     cte as (
      select o.orderid, o.starttime, o.finishtime, o.seqnum
      from  o
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select o.orderid,
             (case when cte.finishtime < o.starttime
                   then o.starttime
                   else cte.finishtime
              end),
             (case when cte.finishtime < o.starttime
                   then o.finishtime
                   else dateadd(second, datediff(second, o.starttime, o.finishtime), cte.finishtime)
              end),
             o.seqnum
      from cte join
           o
           on o.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=454bbc7490c280d34d7ff685b29b8873) is a db<>fiddle.